# htaccess - Remove Query String from URL but Leave Value

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url, url-rewriting

I have searched all over Stackoverflow and Googled wide and far, but I cannot get this seemingly simple task done.

I'm trying to set a rule in htaccess to clean the URL by removing the query string, but leaving its value intact:

`http://example.local/?p=subscribe`

Becomes:

`http://example.local/subscribe`

I have tried these various methods:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

or,

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/?)?$ $1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

or,

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

But nothing works!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. What _exactly_ do you mean by "removing the query string". Which is the URL requested in the browser and what request should that URL get rewritten or redirected to?

Comment: Basically rewrite the url so that the query string "?p=" gets removed. But without removing the last part "subscribe".

`/?p=subscribe` becomes `/subscribe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^?]*?)/?\?p=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect! - Thank you Anubhava, that did the trick. I appreciate your help.

Comment: New problem: I updated the .htaccess on the live server, where phpList is in a subdirectory: `http://example.com/mailinglist/?p=subscribe` Now the rules are no longer working. I've tried adding `RewriteBase /mailinglist/` to the rule set, but it did nothing. I also tried removing trailing `/` dashes, and even typing `mailinglist/` where I thought it would work. Help!

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the `/mailinglist` subdirectory. The parent, `example.com` is a Wordpress installation with it's own, separate htaccess file.

Comment: Well, with the updated code, the site first redirects to `http://example.com/mailinglist//subscribe` (yes, that's two slashes) but immediately after it redirects back to the root `http://example.com/mailinglist/`.

Comment: Double slash will be gone with updated rule but I have no rule that makes `http://example.com/mailinglist//subscribe` to `http://example.com/mailinglist/`

Comment: Yes, the double slash is gone. But somehow all links are redirecting to the root for no apparent reason. I'm not a programmer, but perhaps this behavior is being triggered by something in the php code inside phpList. I should clarify that the redirection happens this way: `http://example.com/mailinglist/?p=subscribe` -> `http://example.com/mailinglist/subscribe` -> `http://example.com/mailinglist/`. Perhaps I should inquire in the phpList discussion group to see if I can get any insights on this anomaly. Thanks Anubhava.

Comment: What gets me is, why do the rules (prior to your last update) work fine on my local machine. The only difference is that on my local machine, phpList is served from root and not a subdirectory.

Comment: You're not the only one facing this challenge. Many things can change from one host to another. I cannot speculate but if you need concrete information then enable `RewriteLog` on new host and check logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use % to retrieve a rewriteCond Variables

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ %1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Will convert any url http:/site.com/url?qs to http:/site.com/qs

Comment: Thank you R. Martin, but the result ends up being a '404' error:

Typing `http://tssl-list.dev/?p=preferences` is not found and the url changes to:


`http://tssl-list.dev/home/alan/Public/tssl-list/preferences`

Comment: @AlanW: Try: `RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]`

Comment: @anubhava - Thank you, it almost worked. The query string did disappear and the URL is properly formed: `http://tssl-list.dev/preferences`. However, it still throws a **404 Not Found**.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but the site is actually a phpList implementation.